# map scroll gesture and add gesture confused

Tags: swift

I have two gesture in my code one that add a pin on the map by touching and other one that remove the old pin.
The problem is that the add gesture get confused with the scroll map gesture, when I scroll on the map it makes me adding pin and not drag sometimes

class PlaceYourPinpointViewController: UIViewController, UIGestureRecognizerDelegate {

```
// MARK: - Variables

@IBOutlet weak var mapView: MKMapView!
@IBOutlet weak var nextBarButton: UIBarButtonItem!
let annotation = MKPointAnnotation()

// MARK: - IOS Basic

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    addAnnotationGesture()
}

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    setLaunchZoom()
}

// MARK: - Actions

@IBAction func cancel() {
    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}

@objc func addPin(gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) {
    let touchPoint = gestureRecognizer.location(in: mapView)
    let newCoordinates = mapView.convert(touchPoint, toCoordinateFrom: mapView)

    annotation.coordinate = newCoordinates
    self.mapView.addAnnotation(annotation)
    nextBarButton.isEnabled = true
}

@objc func removePin(gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) {
    self.mapView.removeAnnotation(annotation)
}

// MARK: - Private Methods

func addAnnotationGesture() {
    let addAnnotationGesture = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(addPin))
    addAnnotationGesture.minimumPressDuration = 0.065
    mapView.addGestureRecognizer(addAnnotationGesture)

    let removeAnnotationGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(removePin))
    removeAnnotationGesture.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
    self.mapView.addGestureRecognizer(removeAnnotationGesture)

}

func setLaunchZoom() {
    let region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: mapView.userLocation.coordinate, latitudinalMeters: 600, longitudinalMeters: 600)
    mapView.setRegion(mapView.regionThatFits(region), animated: true)
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To avoid gesture recognisers conflicting with each other you can set them to fire conditionally. For instance you can prevent the long press gesture from firing unless the pan (drag/scrolling) gesture fails:

**First add a gesture recogniser for scrolling gestures:**

```
let panGesture = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: nil)
panGesture.delegate = self
mapView.addGestureRecognizer(panGesture)
```

**Then implement the `shouldBeRequiredToFailBy` method:**

```
func gestureRecognizer(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, 
         shouldBeRequiredToFailBy otherGestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {
   // Do not begin the long press unless the pan fails. 
   if gestureRecognizer == self.panGesture && 
          otherGestureRecognizer == self.addAnnotationGesture {
      return true
   }
   return false
}
```

*Also refer to the documentation on "[Preferring One Gesture Over Another](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/touches_presses_and_gestures/coordinating_multiple_gesture_recognizers/preferring_one_gesture_over_another)".*

Comment: thank you, but how do I detect when user is scrolling ?

Comment: @mathiasmerlot The first code snippet in my answer addresses this, create a pan (scrolling) gesture recogniser and add it the map view.

Comment: @mathiasmerlot Attaching callback function to action isn't required, you can set action to nil.

Comment: I would like to add my pin still with my long press but I would like the long press to be "addAnnotationGesture.minimumPressDuration = 0" but when I set 0 I get confused with dragging gesture on the map and can not drag anymore